# How are Tabris mobile browser clients created?

Tags: mobile

Tabris has native mobile and browser clients. I see info on creating the native mobile clients. How do you create a mobile browser client?  I would like to use the browser for things that wont need access to native device things like the camera.  I know how to create a standard desktop client using Eclipse RAP.

Answer (score 0):

Tabris' native mobile clients are faster and look nicer (native widgets) on mobile devices. Using a browser on mobile devices to access a RAP server is often slow or suffers from buggy mobile browsers. That's why I would recommend to always use the native client on a mobile device instead of a browser.

In case you want to try to access the RAP server with a mobile browser, just enter the IP and entry point in the URL field of the browser. The RAP client is then fetched via http as it is embedded in the first page you receive from the RAP server.